# Cannot run scripts using VirtualBox with Ubuntu installed

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, virtualbox

I'm doing a tutorial through lydna.com on setting up linux using virtualbox.

It was going fine until I had to create a file in my development folder. It's been set up as a shared folder so I can write html files straight on to the virtual server (I think).

I'm writing small scripts in to the shared folder and I'm getting a 404 error for each. For something like http://sandbox.dev:8080/errors.php or http://sandbox.dev:8080/hello.html (with just a 'hello world' in there).

Additional Info;

In VirtualBox if I go settings->shared folders->machine folders, my 'sandbox' folder is definitely the one being used.

When I go to http://sandbox.dev:8080/server-status - it works as expected. Information about the server.

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I've installed a lot of packages. Things started going wrong on the 'Configuring the Apache web server' section so maybe it's an apache problem.

I have looked on the server through the command line at /var/www/html. It's looks nothing like the shared folder. Just one index.html which - when looking at it in nano - tells me it's the default ubuntu homepage. But I cannot navigate to it in the URL at all.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Update apache2.conf by adding directory directive similar but according to your folder's path:

```
<Directory /mnt/hgfs/sandbox"
  Options Indexes  FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride None
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

My confusion was similar to yours - the link [sandbox.dev/server-status](http://sandbox.dev/server-status) works, so why not anything else.
By the way I am having this issue because I am adjusting the Jon Peck's instructions to VMware Fusion and Workstation. On VM Workstation no problems what so ever, but my preferred dev environment is on OS X and there VM Fusion (Pro 7.0.1) behave different from its Windows sister - the line .host:/  in the file /etc/fstab doesn't have effect where the share folder sandbox is - it goes by default under /mnt/hgfs.

I gave up adjusting VM Fusion - even open-vm-tools could not help, so will follow Jon Peck's instructions to the letter with VirtualBox and I can share with you if I will have that issue.

Comment: Hi @korfer this time I used VirtualBox and everything worked as shown in the videos. Please review the 3rd video in 4th chapter, namely  "Configuring group permissions for access" because that is place causing the issue you described